# VS2015 annoying message about IIS Express

Tags: visual-studio, iis, visual-studio-2015, msbuild, iis-express

I use devenv.com to build my projects from the command line. For various reasons I do not use msbuild for that.

The problem I have with VS2015 (not VS2013) is that I sometimes get a dialog like this:

[image]

The only way known to me to make it go away is open the VS 2015 GUI and build the solution there. It needs to be done just once, but it is annoying in the first place, because the command line build is stuck until OK is pressed. Plus this could happen again.

A few notes about my setup:

1. IISExpress. Please, do not suggest moving to IIS.
2. We do not use the local applicationhost.config from the `.vs` folder. The global one from `%USERPROFILE%\Documents\IISExpress\Config` is used instead. We enforce it for all the projects in all the solutions by including `<UseGlobalApplicationHostFile>True</UseGlobalApplicationHostFile>` in each and every project (through a common targets file).
3. My command line build script knows to create the web application site in the global applicationhost.config, so in VS 2013 the script could be used even if no sites were initially configured - they are configured on the fly, just like VS 2013 GUI does. However, this no longer works in VS2015 - it opens this bloody dialog.

What additional command line configuration needs to be done to avoid this dialog?

Comment: Are you sure the global applicationHost.config and project files (like .csproj) are in sync?

Comment: I am sure, but maybe I am missing anything. What do you have in mind?

Comment: I do have a blog post on the details, https://medium.com/lextm/jexus-manager-secrets-behind-visual-studio-iis-express-integration-834f88c8e8b#.8bc3escok you might verify if you miss anything.

Comment: Both the project and the applicationhost.config files are in sync, relative to the things mentioned in the post - protocol, host name, ports. We use localhost with plain HTTP.

Answer (score 0):

When you open VS 2015 for the solution, the first thing it does is to repopulate the applicationhost.config file inside the local .VS folder. But if you rebuild your project using Devenv.com command line, it will not automatically regenerate the .vs config file correctly.

So I agree with Lex Li, we might ignored a few inconformity. You can try to closed Visual Studio and then deleted the entries for your site in the applicationhost.config. Then opened project in Visual Studio and reconfigured everything before trying to run it. Or using devenv.com to build a new projects from the command line.

Comment: I have just added a clarification to the post. VS does not configure any sites in the .vs\applicationhost.config because all the projects suppress it by including     `<UseGlobalApplicationHostFile>True</UseGlobalApplicationHostFile>`

Comment: Have you try to create a new project without that suppress settings, in order to eliminate this setting cause that issue?

Answer (score 0):

I just copied the *applicationhost.config* file from the project directory `...\.vs\...\config`folder to the IISExpress config folder located under `%USERPROFILE%\Documents\IISExpress\config`.

So I overwrote the global config applicationhost.config file, but in my case it was OK as it is the only VS project on my computer.
Careful when doing this when you've got more projects on your computer as connections may break.